# two routes in routing.yml?

Tags: symfony, routes

I ask if we would add two routes in the file

because I have this error:

```
No route found for "GET /blog"
```

Thanks you for your help

/app/config/routing.yml

```
rubens_blog:
    resource: "@RubensBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /blog/

rubens_admin:
    resource: "@RubensAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

/src/Rubens/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
post_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:index }

post_archives:
    pattern:  /post/archives
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:archives }

post_show:
    pattern:  /post/show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:show }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

/src/Rubens/Bundle/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
 post_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: RubensBlogBundle:Post:index }

 post_archives:
    pattern:  /archives
    defaults: { _controller: RubensBlogBundle:Post:archives }
```

Comment: Use the web debug toolbar to see what routing rules have been registered.

Comment: [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:
[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /blog"

Comment: FYI You can click on the debug toolbar and then go to the "Routing" section. It lists all your routing rules and which one has been matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redefined route name. Your name must be unique:

```
rubens_blog:
    resource: "@RubensBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /blog/

rubens_admin:
    resource: "@RubensAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

/src/Rubens/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
admin_post_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:index }

admin_post_archives:
    pattern:  /post/archives
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:archives }
admin_post_show:
    pattern:  /post/show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:show }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

/src/Rubens/Bundle/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
 blog_post_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: RubensBlogBundle:Post:index }

 blog_post_archives:
    pattern:  /archives
    defaults: { _controller: RubensBlogBundle:Post:archives }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed trailing slash `/` in `/blog`. Try to open next page in browser:

```
/blog/
```

or remove prefix:

```
rubens_blog:
    resource: "@RubensBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

and change route to:

```
post_homepage:
    pattern:  /blog
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:index }

post_archives:
    pattern:  /blog/post/archives
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:archives }

post_show:
    pattern:  /blog/post/show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: RubensAdminBundle:Post:show }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

Comment: clear cache, please (remove dirs `prod` and `dev` in `app/cache`)

Comment: Do you tested and `/blog/` and `/blog` and `/web/blog/` and `/web/blog` ?